# inserting a number into new string causes error

Tags: c++

I couldn't find it anywhere so here I am

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
  

int main()
{
    string napis;
    string new_napis = "";

    cout << "Give string: " << endl;
    cin >> napis;
    int length = napis.length();

    string search = "pies";
    size_t position = napis.find(search);

    if (position != string::npos){
        cout << "Found on position: " << position << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++){
       if (napis[i] > 96 && napis[i] < 123){
         new_napis.insert(i, 1, napis[i]);
       } else {
            cout << "";
       }
    }
    
    cout << "string without numbers: " << new_napis;
    
    

    

    return 0;
}
```

That's the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::insert: __pos (which is 1) > this->size() (which is 0)
```

Basicly what im trying to do here is to take a string from input and convert it to new string but without numbers and other stuff, just pure letters, I found somewhere on the internet that the i <= lenght might be a problem but when i changed it to i = lenght it didn't do anything, just copy paste the old string

Comment: `string new_napis = "";` creates an empty string, just like `string new_napis;` would. You could use `+=` or `push_back()` to add characters to the end that meet your criteria. `i <= length` will also access the string out of bounds, it should be `<`.

Comment: `i <= lenght` definitely is a problem, since it causes `napis[i]` being acessed  out of bounds.

Comment: Note, when `napis[i]` is not between 96 and 123, `i` still increases but `new_napis` doesn't. The error is raised the next time you call `insert`.

Comment: Don't make readers of your code (including your future self) guess at what your code is supposed to do. `if (napis[i] > 96 && napis[i] < 123)` should be changed to use a function whose name describes what that condition means. I'm guessing that the code is ascii-ist, and that that test is supposed to detect a lowercase letter. That's already done for you in the standard library: `if (std::islower(napis[I]))` is much clearer, and will give the correct result even if the character encoding isn't ASCII (granted, that's quite unusual, but don't build in non-portabilities if you don't need to).

Comment: Also, if you want to copy **all** letters you need to copy all letters, not just lowercase ones. So `if (std::isalpha(lapis[I]))` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems related to out-of-range accesses with your code:

1. The correct way to walk `napis` is to go from `0` to `length - 1`, so the check you need to do is `i < length`.
2. If you want to add new non-digit characters at the end of `new_napis` via `insert`, you will need to keep a counter of the characters in `new_napis`, to use as the `pos` parameter for `insert`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/hdvYTqGq5)

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string napis;
    std::string new_napis;

    std::cout << "Give string: \n";
    std::cin >> napis;
    int length = napis.length();
    fmt::print("{} ({})\n", napis, length);

    std::string search = "pies";
    size_t position = napis.find(search);

    if (position != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << "Found on position: " << position << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not found\n";
    }

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (napis[i] > 96 && napis[i] < 123) {
            new_napis.insert(j++, 1, napis[i]);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "string without numbers: " << new_napis;
}

// Outputs:
//
//   Give string: 
//   spe12cia34l (11)
//   Not found
//   string without numbers: special
```

---

Another option to create `new_napis` would be to use:

- `std::copy_if` to walk `napis` and copy characters to `new_napis` if a predicate is met, and
- `std::islower` to check if a character is a lowercase letter.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/W3dPc6GPh)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // copy_if
#include <cctype>  // islower

std::string new_napis;
std::ranges::copy_if(napis, std::back_inserter(new_napis),
    [](unsigned char c){ return std::islower(c); });
```